# Name Server Check fails for .de domain

Tags: nameserver

I've registered a .de domain but when I try to change the nameservers to those of the hosting company I wish to use I get the following error:

```
> Command failed; [53300102912
> Nameserver error [ERROR: 116 SOA
> record response must be authoritative
> (resolver\, answer)
> (\[/10.121.46.7|/2001:608:6:7:4:0:0:11\]=>85.92.74.12:53
> (UDP\, PROTOCOL_EXPLICITLY_CHOSEN\,
> Timeout: 3s\, Retry: 1 x 0s\,
> unsecure\, ignoreTC)\,
> \[/10.121.46.7|/2001:608:6:7:4:0:0:11\]=>85.92.74.12:53
> (UDP\, PROTOCOL_EXPLICITLY_CHOSEN\,
> Timeout: 3s\, Retry: 1 x 0s\,
> unsecure\, ignoreTC): )]]
> 
> If you wish to change your
> nameservers, you need to make sure
> they are configured according to DENIC
> (the .de registry) rules.
```

It also points me at the [DENIC website nameserver check](http://www.denic.de/en/background/nast.html) which tells me that the domains fail, much the same error as above, as is expected.

So the question is, what do I need to do? Is it something that my hosting provider will need to sort out with their nameservers, or can I do something about it myself?

Any thoughts and help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check at your hosting company if the DNS was configured as a master server for your domain. If you added entries (A, CNAME, etc.) it should have been, but it seems to be answering that it's not authoritative for it.

This shows that the domain has other name servers configured right now (ns and ns2.123-reg.go.uk):

```
$ dig ns iandevlin.de 

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> ns iandevlin.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9583
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;iandevlin.de.                  IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
iandevlin.de.           86376   IN      NS      ns.123-reg.co.uk.
iandevlin.de.           86376   IN      NS      ns2.123-reg.co.uk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.123-reg.co.uk.       7066    IN      A       212.67.202.2
ns2.123-reg.co.uk.      7066    IN      A       92.51.159.40

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon May 30 08:33:23 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
```

This shows that the DNS of your hosting service *is not* answering queries for your domain (85.92.74.12 *is* the DNS of your hosting service, right?):

```
$ dig @85.92.74.12 iandevlin.de

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @85.92.74.12 iandevlin.de
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16387
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 13
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;iandevlin.de.                  IN      A

### (snip)

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
a.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      AAAA    2001:503:ba3e::2:30
b.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       192.228.79.201
c.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       192.33.4.12
d.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       128.8.10.90
e.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       192.203.230.10
f.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      AAAA    2001:500:2f::f
g.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       192.112.36.4
h.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       128.63.2.53
h.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      AAAA    2001:500:1::803f:235
i.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      A       192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net.     599044  IN      AAAA    2001:7fe::53

;; Query time: 240 msec
;; SERVER: 85.92.74.12#53(85.92.74.12)
;; WHEN: Mon May 30 08:33:52 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 497
```

So double-check the configuration on your hosting provider and make sure you're using the right domain name servers.

Comment: Hmm you have me at a disadvantage here, as I'm not great with such things and you may need to explain things a bit more! Where should I run dig from?

Comment: @Ian - I should've been clearer, of course! You can run `dig` from any Linux server. The Windows equivalent is, I think, `nslookup`; but it has a different syntax.

Comment: That command lets you see yourself the DNS response from your hosting service. The idea is to check for anomalies or errors reported directly by the hosting provider. You can post the domain name and I'll check it if you want.

Comment: Please (sorry), domain is iandevlin.de

Comment: If 85.92.74.12 is the DNS of your hosting provider it is indeed not answering queries for your domain (see added information). So check the settings on your hosting provider's control panel.

Comment: Well this is the issue. The domain is registered with someone else (123-reg), and when I try to redirect the nameservers to my hosting company's ones, it fails because of the issue I mentioned. So perhaps I'm stuck in a loop here?

Comment: I'm not sure about the `.de` administrative procedures but if it's registered with `123-reg` you may need to change the DNS entries on 123-reg's control panel instead.

Comment: Well that's what I've been trying to do, but it fails due to the nameserver issue.

Comment: I thought you were trying to make the change on DENIC itself, sorry. If you configure it right the hosting provider's DNS should answer queries independently of whether it's already the "primary" nameserver (pointed by 123-reg) or not. So check there.

Comment: Thanks but I have no idea what any of that means, DNS and nameservers and the like is a complete black art to me :-( It's always worked fine with other domains, it's just this .de one that causes issues as .de domains have stricter rules and it seems that my hosting company doesn't have their nameservers set up correctly. They're also very slow to respond to support emails, so guess I just have to wait. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's all good now, it was a catch 22 situation which the hosting company sorted out. Even though you didn't give the answer, it was impossible to do so, you get the answer points anyway simply because you helped! Thanks!